# fstream doesnt write and make files

Tags: c++, fstream

In have a problem in my Code. I wanna use fstream to make files and also to write to files, but it does only make one File and doesnt write anything to it and the other two arent made.
I hope somebody can help me.
The PlayerMake ofstream file is made and the other two arent made.

```
std::string line;

        std::ifstream nameFree;
        nameFree.open(PlayerList);

        if (nameFree.is_open()) {
            while (std::getline(nameFree, line)) {
                if (line == name) {
                    std::cout << "Dieser Name ist leider bereits belegt. Bitte suche dir einen anderen aus." << std::endl;
                    nameFree.close();
                    Neu();
                }
                else {
                    std::string FileCreateCPP = "D:/Doucments/Game/" + name + ".cpp";
                    std::string FileCreateTXT = "D:/Doucments/Game/" + name + ".txt";

                    nameFree.close();

                    std::ofstream PlayerMake;
                    PlayerMake.open(PlayerList, std::ios::app);

                    std::ofstream cpp;
                    cpp.open(FileCreateCPP);

                    std::ofstream txt;
                    txt.open(FileCreateTXT);

                    if (cpp.is_open() && txt.is_open()) {
                        cpp << name;
                        PlayerMake << name << std::endl;
                        PlayerMake.close();
                        cpp.close();
                        txt.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cerr << "Fehler beim erstellen deines Kontos 1" << std::endl;
                        cpp.close();
                        txt.close();
                        Neu();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Fehler beim erstellen deines Kontos 2" << std::endl;
            Neu();
        }
    }
```

I did some testing now and made my Code a little bit better and recognized, that the code, with std::cout << "Hallo" << std::endl; doesnt get runned.

```
    int Free = 0;
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Hi. Bitte gebe deinen Namen für den neuen Spielstand ein und bestaetige es mit Enter. Falls du wieder zurück möchtest, gebe 'Exit' ein und bestaetige es ebenfalls mit Enter." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;

    if (name == "Exit") {
        main();
    }
    else {
        std::string line;

        std::ifstream nameFree;
        nameFree.open(PlayerList);

        if (nameFree.is_open()) {
            while (std::getline(nameFree, line)) {
                if (line == name) {
                    std::cout << "Dieser Name ist leider bereits belegt. Bitte suche dir einen anderen aus." << std::endl;
                    Free == 0;
                    Neu();
                }
                else {
                    Free == 1;
                }
            }

            nameFree.close();

            if (Free == 1) {
                std::cout << "Hallo" << std::endl;

                std::string FileCreateCPP = "D:/Doucments/Game/Players/" + name + ".cpp";
                std::string FileCreateTXT = "D:/Doucments/Game/" + name + ".txt";

                std::ofstream PlayerMake;
                PlayerMake.open(PlayerList, std::ios::app);

                std::ofstream cpp;
                cpp.open(FileCreateCPP);

                std::ofstream txt;
                txt.open(FileCreateTXT);

                if (cpp.is_open() && txt.is_open()) {
                    cpp << name;
                    PlayerMake << name << std::endl;
                    PlayerMake.close();
                    cpp.close();
                    txt.close();
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "Fehler beim erstellen deines Kontos 1" << std::endl;
                    cpp.close();
                    txt.close();
                    Neu();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Fehler beim erstellen deines Kontos 2" << std::endl;
            Neu();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code you are able to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

std::string PlayerList = "C:/PlayerList.txt";


void Neu() {
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Hi. Bitte gebe deinen Namen für den neuen Spielstand ein und bestaetige es mit Enter. Falls du wieder zurück möchtest, gebe 'Exit' ein und bestaetige es ebenfalls mit Enter." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;

    if (name == "Exit") {

    }
    else {
        std::string line;

        std::ifstream nameFree;
        nameFree.open(PlayerList);

        if (nameFree.is_open()) {
            while (std::getline(nameFree, line)) {
                if (line == name) {
                    std::cout << "Dieser Name ist leider bereits belegt. Bitte suche dir einen anderen aus." << std::endl;
                    nameFree.close();
                    Neu();
                }
                else {
                    std::string FileCreateCPP = "D:/Doucments/Game/" + name + ".cpp";
                    std::string FileCreateTXT = "D:/Doucments/Game/" + name + ".txt";

                    nameFree.close();

                    std::ofstream PlayerMake;
                    PlayerMake.open(PlayerList, std::ios::app);

                    std::ofstream cpp;
                    cpp.open(FileCreateCPP);

                    std::ofstream txt;
                    txt.open(FileCreateTXT);

                    if (cpp.is_open() && txt.is_open()) {
                        cpp << name;
                        PlayerMake << name << std::endl;
                        PlayerMake.close();
                        cpp.close();
                        txt.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cerr << "Fehler beim erstellen deines Kontos 1" << std::endl;
                        cpp.close();
                        txt.close();
                        Neu();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Fehler beim erstellen deines Kontos 2" << std::endl;
            Neu();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `D:/Doucments` a typo?

Comment: The `else` gets executed each time `line != name`. I think you want to move the `else` block out of the `while` so it only gets executed if the name is not found.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You can use forward slashes `/` on Windows as well as on other operating systems.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think the `Doucments` part is what the typo was about.

Comment: ´How excatly would that work with moving the else out of the while?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hehe, you are probably right. I completely missed that.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes. Documents is a typo. I made it. All the paths are available

Comment: @Bugsia Make a [mcve] - something that compiles for you and will compile for us, with those typos fixed.

Comment: Why do you close `nameFree`? Your code only ever reads the first line of that file.

Comment: If you removed the lines that close `nameFree` and remove the recursive calls, `Neu();`. I think you'd be closer to working code.

Comment: @john Because i opened it and im gonna use the same file later, so i wanna it to be close, so it can open it with an ofstream

Comment: @john even when i delete these lines, it does still do nothing

Comment: @Bugsia Because you close the file after reading the first line, it means that the next time you open the file you are going to read the first line again. Your code will never read the second line of the file. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Bugsia Well I didn't say that making that change would give you a working program, you probably have lots of bugs and you need to fix them all.

Comment: Okay, Sorry. It still doesnt work. Does somebody have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the code is trying to create a new user. You check the `PlayerList` to see if the name exists - except you only check the first name in the list because of the `else`.

Note in my code I never have to call `close()`. The destructors will do that.

```
// Adding a helper function to simplify
bool nameExists(std::string name, std::string path)
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream nameFree(path);
    if (nameFree) {
        while (std::getline(nameFree, line)) {
            if (line == name) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Returns false if user enters "Exit" or file error
bool Neu(std::string path)
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Hi. Bitte gebe deinen Namen für den neuen Spielstand ein und bestaetige es mit Enter. Falls du wieder zurück möchtest, gebe 'Exit' ein und bestaetige es ebenfalls mit Enter." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;

    if (name == "Exit") {
        return false;
    }
    // Check if name already exists...
    if (nameExists(name, path)) {
        // It does. Try again
        std::cout << "Dieser Name ist leider bereits belegt. Bitte suche dir einen anderen aus." << std::endl;
        return Neu(path);
    }
    else {
        // It does not exist. Add it.
        std::string FileCreateCPP = "D:/Doucments/Game/" + name + ".cpp";
        std::string FileCreateTXT = "D:/Doucments/Game/" + name + ".txt";

        // TODO: make sure name does not contain any characters
        // that are not allowed by OS in file names

        std::ofstream PlayerMake(path, std::ios::app);
        std::ofstream cpp(FileCreateCPP);
        std::ofstream txt(FileCreateTXT);

        if (PlayerMake && cpp && txt) {
            cpp << name;
            PlayerMake << name << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    while (Neu("C:/PlayerList.txt")) {
        std::cout << "Player created\n";
    }
}
```